# Q : MDC TextField margin

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-components

as far as I understood, using Sass Mixins is the proper way to customize an MDC element. I have an issue regarding [MDC TextField](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/tree/master/packages/text-field) : I am using multiple outlined TextFields to create a form, TextFields are set that way :

```
<TextField label="Foo" outlined={true} dense={true}>
    <Input
        name="item.foo"
        value={item.foo}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
</TextField>
<p />
<TextField label="Bar" outlined={true} dense={true}>
    <Input
        name="item.bar"
        value={item.bar}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
</TextField>
```

The issue : floating labels on the top left are overlaping the previous field, in that case, a floating 'Bar' will overlap the outline of the previous element.
To solve this I used a scss file containing this :

```
.mdc-text-field {
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

This is working as intended and solves the overlap issue, but I don't know if I am doing it correctly as I thought only Sass Mixins are the proper way to customize MDC elements.